# xamarin - seems cashed in Emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, vs-community-edition

I created a app called app1 and was using in Emulator.
Then say i created app called Hotdog complete new solution , but it always come with app1 and HotDog does not apper.

I am following a online tutorial...so not doing something out of box

1) i created a blank solution in .net
2) added new project Android
3) i am using community edition and i5 processor

I have tried creating new solution and also launching it, multiple times.
tried clean build, rebuild...
[it sometimes says deployment error, though my application is just in default state : click counter (i have changed text but new text does not appear only old text from old application appears)]

This is stopping me from creating new application as i am not able to deploy, sometimes it deploys but only old application appears
kind of stuck, either i am missing some step please guide

copied some part of build (as its huge)

2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

```
2>HotDog -> C:\Rahul\Development\AndriodApplication\HotDog\bin\Debug\HotDog.dll
2>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
2>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554  shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
2>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554  shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist64 
2>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554  shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi 
2>:Deployment failed
2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
2>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()<---
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: i created a new application without blank solution (rather creating blank solution and adding andriod app to it). Now i created a new blank andriod solution. still the emulator has cashed by 3 day old o/p. I resstarted my machine number of time and even visual studio. There is no build error error now as i am creating blank andriod application

Comment: i created a new application without blank solution (rather creating blank solution and adding andriod app to it). Now i created a new blank andriod solution. still the emulator has cashed by 3 day old o/p. I resstarted my machine number of time and even visual studio. There is no build error error now as i am creating blank andriod application. The emulator i am using is "5554:Andriod_Accelerated_x86  (Andriod 6.0 Api 23)" also tried "Andriod _Armv7a "

Comment: I finally got resolved..i know my title of issue is not clear..initially i thought thats what is happening.  1) the visual studio and emulator is too slow and adds to confusion. 2) To resolve issue i had to uninstall xamarin and restart computer 3) then rebuild my solution initiate the emulator and wait for long time 4) then it got resolved now